# confusion in dapper multi mapping scenario

Tags: c#, dapper

I have read about dapper multi mapping but what I got out of it is,if I have two tables which are connected through m_turbine_id ,accordingly I have two classes correspond  to these tables:

### Test Class

```
public string turbine_name { get; set; }
public int m_turbine_id { get; set; }
```

### TestMaster Class

```
 public DateTime m_date { get; set; }
 public double m_energy_prod { get; set; }
 public int m_turbine_id { get; set; }
```

now I want to get **turbine_name** and **m_energy_prod** ,in this scenario I should use multimapping?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, maybe not. In many cases it would be more appropriate to have a type (presumably a POCO intended for display purposes) that has all the properties you want to display, and simply do a join (presumably an `inner` join) at the database, selecting the properties you want; so:

```
var items = conn.Query<YourDisplayType>(@"
     select t.turbine_name, se.energy_prod, se.date
     from turbines t
     inner join somethingelse se on t.turbine_id = se.turbine_id
     where ... (whatevver)", new {...}").AsList();
```

where `YourDisplayType` has a matching structure.

Comment: so,when it is useful to use multi mapping"?

Comment: @papagallo when you really want to get separate objects :)

Comment: here also I want different objects,from different tables ,sorry marc im just confused

Comment: @papagallo if you really want two objects, then yes: multi-map might be an option; it just isn't *automatically* the preferred option

Comment: can you please write it in multi mapping way?using split?please?